# Strategy when retrieving user name from session

Tags: java, html, jsp, jakarta-ee, jsp-fragments

I have a technical problem and I am not sure about the correct way to solve:

In a web page I am developing, I have to store the current user name from session (the person who is logged in) to "stamp" an action. (For instance, "The user  created this file on "). My algorithm retrieves the user name from session but it obviously changes for each user. Therefore, the  is always been the one of the user logged in, and not the creator name.

Any hint anyone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So logically these are the steps you want?

- User1 logs in
- User1's name gets stored in Http session
- User1 creates File42
- System stores in database that User1 created File42 on Timestamp257
- User1 logs out
- User 2 logs in
- User2's name gets stored in Http session
- User2 views information about File42
- System reads from database that User1 created File42 on Timestamp257
- System displays information to User2

I think you might be missing the part where the system stores stuff (e.g. in a database).

EDIT: If you don't need persistence you could store shared data in the ServletContext. Note this is not a serious solution but could be used for a quick prototype or demo. Don't even think about doing this in production, it's got issues.

In your servlet do:

```
private static Map<String, FileData> fileAccess;

private class FileData {
    String userName;
    Date timeStamp = new Date();;
    String fileName;
    FileData(String userName, String fileName) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.fileName= fileName;
    }
}

public void init(ServletConfig config) {
    String attributeKey = "fileAccess";
    fileAccess = config.getServletContext().getAttribute(attributeKey);
    if (fileAccess == null) {
        fileAccess = new HashMap<String, FileData>();
        config.getServletContext().setAttribute(attributeKey, fileAccess);
    }
}

// in this example a POST means a user accesses a file
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {

    // get the user name from the current session
    String userName = req.getSession().getAttribute("userName");

    // get the file name from the request (posted from the file access form)
    String fileName = req.getParameter("fileName");

    // check if we have the necessary data
    if (userName == null || fileName == null) {
        resp.getWriter().write("Invalid file access request");
        resp.getWriter().flush();    
        return;
    }

    // create and fill file data wrapper
    FileData fileData = new FileData(userName, fileName);

    // store the file data in the shared fileAccess map.
    // synchronized to block simultaneous acccess from different threads
    synchronized (fileAccess) {
        // note: any previously stored FileData object gets replaced
        fileAccess.put(fileName, fileData);
    }

    // display the result to the user
    display(fileData, resp);
}

// in this example a GET means a user views a file
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {

    // get the file name parameter from the request (sent as part of the view-file request)
    String fileName = req.getParameter("fileName");

    // check if we have the necessary data
    if (fileName == null) {
        resp.getWriter().write("Invalid view file request.");
        resp.getWriter().flush();    
        return;
    }

    // get the file data from the shared fileAccess map.
    // synchronized to block simultaneous acccess from different threads
    synchronized (fileAccess) {
        FileData  fileData = fileAccess.get(fileName);   

        // display the result to the user
        display(fileData, resp);
    }
}

private void display(FileData fileData, HttpServletResponse resp) {
    resp.getWriter().write("File accessed:");
    resp.getWriter().write("User: " + fileData.userName);
    resp.getWriter().write("File: " + fileData.fileName);
    resp.getWriter().write("Timestamp: " + fileData.timeStamp);
    resp.getWriter().flush();  
}
```

Comment: Exactly my friend, that's exactly what I am looking for. The problem is that, in the last step in your example, system will display to user 2 that "User2 created File42 on Timestamp257" because User2 in this string is just the user from session, when system should display to User2 "User1 created File42 on Timestamp257". Do you know if is there any kind of software pattern to achieve this? Cheers mate.

Comment: Are you storing the file, user and timestamp in a database on the server?

Comment: I am not storing it because I was trying to find a lighter solution to it.

Comment: See the solution I added to my answer. Only use it for prototypes or demo's, not production code.

Comment: Thanks, but I solved the problem some days ago, so I won't yours it nor in prototypes, nor demo, nor production code, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Anyways, it's a really good approach, so I consider it a solution ;-)

Comment: Thanks. So what was the solution you chose in the end?

Comment: You're welcome. I finally created a hidden field where I store the author stamp. I realized that maybe I was trying to reinvent the wheel so I used the simple way and it worked. Thanks again for your time man